# SQL Wildcard at Like Operator with embedded table

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-like

I'm pretty new to SQL programming.
Here's my problem:
With this query:

```
Select Artikelname as Artikel
from Artikel
where Artikelname Like (Select txtFilter from Filter)
```

I would like to add a wildcard to the expression "txtFilter", so that all "Artikelname" are displayed which start with the first letter in the field "txtFilter".

This:

```
Select Artikelname as Artikel
from Artikel
where Artikelname Like ((Select txtFilter from Filter)*)
```

or this:

```
Select Artikelname as Artikel
from Artikel
where Artikelname Like (Select txtFilter from Filter) + "*"
```

does not work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Instead of *, use %.  Check the PostgreSQL documentation for details, it is the most accessible, standards-compliant and complete SQL documentation around.

Answer (score 0):

Use `exists`:

```
Select a.Artikelname as Artikel
from Artikel a
where exists (select 1
              from txtFilter f
              where a.Artikelname like 
              f.textFilter||'%' ;
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a join and then use `LIKE`

```
   Select Artikelname as Artikel
  from Artikel a join (Select distinct 
  txtFilter
  from Filter) f on
   a.Artikelname like f.textFilter||'%' ;
```

Answer (score -1):

The * wildcard is not part of the SQL standard — use % instead.  You can use the LIKE operator with a JOIN, in this case — if I understood what you are striving for.  There are also regular expressions, but they are not universally implemented.  At least PostgreSQL has them.

Comment: That should be a comment

Comment: I do not get it, why?